# How did ancient human deal with biting insects like mosquitos?

Tags: human-evolution

How did early humans, once hairless, but before clothes and ointments.

I understand that hairlessness was an advantage against parasites but it it seems like a disadvantage antagonistic for mosquitos and such.

Comment: I believe your question is based on a wrong assumption: mosquitoes bite furry animals just fine. Having less hair doesn't seem to be a disadvantage against mosquitoes.